# Implementing action buttons with tabulator in Laravel + Vue project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, button, datatable, tabulator

I am using this framework called [Tabulator](https://tabulator.info).

I add a column called Actions where users can perform viewing, editing and deleting records. Those buttons are shown but onclick events ain't working.

```
        initTabulator() {
            this.columns = [
                { title: "Name", field: "name", width: 150 },
                { title: "Status", field: "status", width: 150 },
                {
                    title: "Actions",
                    formatter: function(value, data, type, params, component){
                        return `
                            <span class="border border-slate-300 hover:border-slate-400 bg-red-500" onclick="viewFunc()">View</span>
                            <button class="border border-slate-300 hover:border-slate-400 bg-blue-500">Edit</button>
                            <button class="border border-slate-300 hover:border-slate-400 bg-green-500">Delete</button>
                        `;
                    },
                },
            ];
        },
```

I am expecting that those buttons would trigger my functions, yet it alerts errors that my functions are not defined while in fact my functions are declared.

[image]

Comment: How are your functions defined? Is it in the same file?

Comment: It is in the same file, so basically I define it in methods: {}.

Comment: Maybe try to put viewFunc() function into DOMContentLoaded event? Helped me a lot :)

Comment: How did you define `viewFunc()`? Try to use an arrow function instead of a regular function. Arrow function allows you to access method on the current scope. 

`formatter: (value, data, type, params, component)=> return {.... }`

Comment: thank you! i have got my issue fixed

Comment: I stucked with same. Please can you guide me how you resolved error?